# Why is there no value for 'urls' in this Twitter Standard Search JSON response?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twitter

I am trying to implement a twitter timeline into my website. The links to each individual tweet aren't showing up in the JSON response like they should (according to the docs).

I am building a website that implements a twitter timeline based on tweets that contain a certain phrase. The JSON response that i get from the Twitter Standard Search API is supposed to have a url that links to each tweet that the API gives in the JSON response. Except in my case there is no url.

```
contributors: null
coordinates: null
created_at: ""
entities:
hashtags: [{…}]
symbols: []
urls: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
user_mentions: []
__proto__: Object
favorite_count: 0
favorited: false
geo: null
id: 
id_str: ""
in_reply_to_screen_name: null
in_reply_to_status_id: null
in_reply_to_status_id_str: null
in_reply_to_user_id: null
in_reply_to_user_id_str: null
is_quote_status: false
lang: "en"
metadata: {iso_language_code: "en", result_type: "recent"}
place: null
retweet_count: 0
retweeted: false
source: ""
text: ""
truncated: false
user: {id: , id_str: "", name: "", screen_name: "", location: "", …}
__proto__: Object
```

That is the JSON response (With the personal details of the user removed) if it of any use. I'm just wondering if anyone else has had this issue and how they resolved it. I imagine it could be an authentication issue but i am able to get information about the users specific location so i have no idea why it wouldn't let me get the url of the retrieved tweets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the URL by yourself using the tweet `id` and the `user.name`

```
https://twitter.com/${user.name}/status/${id}
```

For example:

- id = '1075805398714777600'
- user.name = 'StackOverflow'

https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1075805398714777600

Comment: ah ok, is there a specific reason why the urls field has nothing in it though? Just out of curiosity

Comment: `urls` contains the `urls` included in that tweet, for example, if the user mentions a link on their tweet; more information https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object#urls